# Проблема с кнопками и классами `active`

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

```
$(".container ul li").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Когда делаю такой скрипт и совмещаю с навбаром бутстрап вот что происходит : http://i.gyazo.com/eaa737dc76c45b942aa71df9aeaf9ab2.gif Как бы класс актив присваивается и убирается. Как сделать чтобы не убиралось, а оставалось активной пока не нажали на др. ссылку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас срабатывает переход по ссылке, предотвратить переход можно добавив `return false` вконец.

```
$(".container ul li").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    return false
});
```

Comment: Получилось, но мне нужно чтобы на странице по ссылке оно было с классом `.active`)

Comment: не ясно что ещё нужно. вроде `.active` добавляется

Comment: Но по ссылке нужно перейти на другую стр )

Comment: только через ajax

Comment: А как реализовать это?) я даже подключаю bootstrap.js оно все равно не срабатывает. Вроде должно срабатывать.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav - вот это меню

Comment: можно либо переходить по ссылке, либо НЕ переходить. вам чего нужно то?

Comment: Мне нужно переходить по ссылке в тоже время нажатая кнопка не должна терять свойства класса `.active`.

Comment: `http://i.gyazo.com/8e99e12bf7041c68ddaa8d5b00a7aa5a.gif` - вот смотрите  по умолчанию `.active` присвоен ссылке `Главная`. Когда нажимаю `Новинки` она активируется, потому что там в `href="#"` стоит решетка а другие не активируются потому что там ссылка на др. страницу сайта. И там оно должно активироваться  как бы сообщая что мы находимся на этой стр.

Comment: значит скрипта выше вам не нужно. нужно делать обычный переход по ссылке и серверными средствами (например `php`) помечать нужные табы, например: `<ul class="nav nav-tabs"><li <? if ($page=='home') {echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="/">Home</a></li><li <? if ($page=='about') {echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="/about/">About</a></li></ul>` Данный пример - ознакомительный. Если вы его вставите к себе - ничего не заработает. Никто не знает как у вас система построена.

Comment: `http://eshop/view_aystopper.php?go=sale` - через гет нужно взять `sale` присвоить это переменной `$page` пологаю

Comment: `$page = $_GET["go"];`

Comment: Свершилось, вот только как быть с `index.php` как его объявить в перменной?)